# Why do I have an "Invalid argument supplied for foreach" in mysql connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my database connection

```
 try {
        //create PDO connection 
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        //show error
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        exit;
    }
```

I want select some values from my table:

```
$pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT  *  FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC;');
foreach ($pdo->execute($db) as $row) {
    echo $row['name'];              
}
```

But I get two warning messages:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in...
```

And the second warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...
```

---

Edit, for JonStirling:

```
 $pdo = $db->prepare('SELECT  *  FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC;');
 while ($row = $pdo->fetch())  {
        echo $row['name'];  
 }
```

With this solution I do not get any warnings, but also still no results.

Comment: `execute` returns a boolean, not an array. You're probably wanting to execute as a single statements, then use `while` loop on `$pdo->fetch()`.

Comment: @JonStirling Thank you! I tested `while ($pdo->fetch($db) as $row) {` as you suggested, but now the page is not working anymore

Comment: That's not valid `while` syntax.

Comment: ah sorry, understood you wrong, I will check it out!

Comment: @JonStirling I tested `while ($row = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
echo $row['name']; 
}` I do not get any error messages, but I do also not get any results

Comment: I wrote a [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#query) which has everything you need to know to get this code right at last.

Comment: @Jarla When did I say use `fetchAll`...

Comment: @JonStirling I tested ` while ($row = $pdo->fetch())  {
                                            echo $row['name']; 
                                          }` Still no results

Comment: Please provide your latest code to the end of your question. And new error messages too.

Comment: @JonStirling Ok, one second!

Comment: @Jarla ... you removed the `execute`...

Comment: Adding functions at random won't get you anywhere. You have to learn PDO first and then try your first program.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you! I will check it out!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I am learning right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be...

```
$pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY id ASC;');
while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\n" . $row['name'];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @YourCommonSense I found a working answer:

```
   $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM animals');
   foreach ($pdo as $row){
       echo $row['name'];
   }
```